# Nexus 7 2013 with Android L camera issue: onPreviewFrame not called

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-5.0-lollipop

I have very basic camera initialization code that gets me preview on Acer A500 (Android 3.1) and Ainol Novo 9 (Android 4.1.1). I've just bought a Nexus 7 2013, installed Android L preview onto it, and found out my camera-related code no longer works. The camera is initialized successfully, no exceptions being thrown, including the `startPReview()` call. However, `onPreviewFrame` is not being called at all. What could be the reason?

Could it be because I only have a dummy SurfaceView that's not displayed anywhere?

```
private SurfaceView   m_surfaceView = new SurfaceView(CameraTestApplication.instance().getApplicationContext());
private SurfaceHolder m_surfaceHolder = m_surfaceView.getHolder();

void initCamera()
{
   m_openedCamera = Camera.open(0);
   ...
   m_openedCamera.setPreviewDisplay(m_surfaceHolder);
   m_openedCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
   openedCamera.startPreview();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Android L has not been official yet is that right?  I don't think you can typically rely on it being fully functional until the official release.  I know I have run into issues doing that before with the last release and Bluetooth.

Comment: @JaySnayder: that is one possibility.

Comment: @JaySnayder: Just tried the standard Android camera app. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. It was, in fact, related to my artificial `SurfaceView` - what I did was not good enough. However, this works:

```
private SurfaceTexture m_previewTexture = new SurfaceTexture(8743);


void initCamera()
{
   m_openedCamera = Camera.open(0);
   ...
   m_openedCamera.setPreviewTexture(m_previewTexture);
   m_openedCamera.setPreviewCallback(this);
   openedCamera.startPreview();
   ...
}
```